# Superimposing a Vector Field onto a Toroid in Matlab

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, modeling, aerodynamics, wind-power

I am a systems and control PhD student in Aerospace Engineering.  Currently, I am trying to create a wind shear model of a toroidal thermal "bubble" in Matlab similar to the one in this paper (shown on the last page): https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/6.2009-6112

I have figured out how to model just the toroid in Matlab thanks to this helpful bit of code:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46444-visualizing-a-toroidal-surface-torus-in-matlab

For reference, the parameters I used were r = 200, R = 201, and I multiplied the z values by 1.5 to achieve the height I wanted.

But what I want to do now is sort of superimpose a wind shear model to the toroid in such a way that it resembles the figure at the very end of the paper.  I would like to frame it in such a way that I can visualize it with a quiver3 plot so I know the field is flowing properly.  I'm just not sure how to do this, since fluid mechanics and topology aren't really my areas of expertise.

The peak airspeed inside this thermal bubble, in the center of the toroid, should be 3 m/s.  The winds in the rest of the toroid should then weaken accordingly, as in the paper.  I greatly appreciate any help I might receive on this matter.